# How to start "Windows Terminal" via command line?

Tags: command-line, parameter-passing, windows-terminal

I am using Listary (which is a comfortable explorer integration) and I want to be able to start an instance of "Windows Terminal" in the current directory. My Listary command is configured, so that it starts the application under the path

> C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe.

Unfortunately I couldn't find out yet a way to pass a target directory to Windows Terminal as a parameter. It refuses to take any paths and always starts at the `%userprofile%` directory. Is there a way to accomplish this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution, after reading this article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-9-release/

In short, you have just to type "-d ." into the "Parameter" field of Listary's custom command. "." refers to the current directory.

[image]

Comment: Which section of Listary is this screenshot from? Keywords > Custom?